# How to disable logging of wpa_supplicant into syslog

Tags: logs, syslog, wpa-supplicant

My `syslog` is being flooded be the following, which is obviously WLAN connection related.

This question is How to disable logging of `wpa_supplicant` into `syslog`?

```
Nov 16 03:58:14 vb-nb-mint wpa_supplicant[1523]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 30:b5:c2:b9:c8:f2 [GTK=CCMP]
```

**EDIT1:** I think my question is different, because I don't even know what `wpa_supplicant` is doing in the background and not in some script. I am on Mint 18 and just want a clean `syslog` without this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `rsyslog` or similar you can edit your config file `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or similar. Find the line referring to `/var/log/syslog`, for example,

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
```

and insert a line before it to suppress messages with the appropriate program name, eg

```
:programname, isequal, "wpa_supplicant" stop
```

There are other syntaxes for the same thing, depending on what version you have, but this is fairly old and should work with many versions.  Restart your `rsyslog` daemon.

Answer (score 0):

`wpa_supplicant -f /tmp/wpalog ....`

`man wpa_supplicant`:

```
   -f output file
          Log output to specified file instead of stdout.  (This  is  only
          available if wpa_supplicant was built with the CONFIG_DEBUG_FILE
          option.)
```

Comment: It's permanent if you use `-f` parameter in your permanent script.